# How do I apply a function to row subsets of a data.table where each call returns a data.table

Tags: r, data.table

Here's a data.table

```
dt <- data.table(group = c("a","a","a","b","b","b"), x = c(1,3,5,1,3,5), y= c(3,5,8,2,8,9))
dt
   group x y
1:     a 1 3
2:     a 3 5
3:     a 5 8
4:     b 1 2
5:     b 3 8
6:     b 5 9
```

And here's a function that operates on a data.table and returns a data.table

```
myfunc <- function(dt){
  # Hyman spline interpolation (which preserves monotonicity)

  newdt <- data.table(x = seq(min(dt$x), max(dt$x)))
  newdt$y <- spline(x = dt$x, y = dt$y, xout = newdt$x, method = "hyman")$y
  return(newdt)
}
```

How do I apply `myfunc` to each subset of dt defined by the "group" column?  In other words, I want an efficient, generalized way to do this

```
result <- rbind(myfunc(dt[group=="a"]), myfunc(dt[group=="b"]))
result
    x     y
 1: 1 3.000
 2: 2 3.875
 3: 3 5.000
 4: 4 6.375
 5: 5 8.000
 6: 1 2.000
 7: 2 5.688
 8: 3 8.000
 9: 4 8.875
10: 5 9.000
```

EDIT: I've updated my sample dataset and `myfunc` because I think it was initially too simplistic and invited work-arounds to the actual problem I'm trying to solve.

Comment: You function creates unnecessary copies, Just do `dt[, .(x = seq(min(x), max(x) + 1), y = rep(y, each = 2)), by = group]`

Comment: Alternately, define your function as following `myfunc <- function(x, y){
  list(x = seq(min(x), max(x)+1), y = rep(y, each=2))}` and then do `dt[, myfunc(x, y), by = group]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg see my edit (sorry)

Comment: @Ben, @DavidArenburg 's comment still holds. Have your function return a list, not a data.table, and do `dt[, myfunc(x, y), by = group]`.

Comment: Actually your new function returns an error now.

Comment: @DavidArenburg be sure to use my updated dataset

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The whole idea of `data.table` is being both memory efficient and fast. Thus we never use `$` within the `data.table` scope (only in very rare situations) and we don't create `data.table` objects within `data.table`s environment (currently, even `.SD` has an overhead).

In your case you can take advantage of `data.table`'s [non-standard evaluation](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html) capabilities and define your function as follows

```
myfunc <- function(x, y){
   temp = seq(min(x), max(x))
   y = spline(x = x, y = y, xout = temp, method = "hyman")$y
   list(x = temp, y = y)
}
```

Then the implementation within the `dt` scope is straight forward

```
dt[, myfunc(x, y), by = group]
#     group x      y
#  1:     a 1 3.0000
#  2:     a 2 3.8750
#  3:     a 3 5.0000
#  4:     a 4 6.3750
#  5:     a 5 8.0000
#  6:     b 1 2.0000
#  7:     b 2 5.6875
#  8:     b 3 8.0000
#  9:     b 4 8.8750
# 10:     b 5 9.0000
```

Comment: NSE is "non-standard evaluation", eh? So suggests google, anyway.